# Why am I getting the same output from different codes?

Tags: database, query-optimization, ssas, mdx, mdx-query

So, I've been learning MDX and I came across some basic data querying along multiple dimensions.

The concept of tuples and sets are kind of clear for me.

What's the query supposed to do: show a measure across multiple dimensions

Code 1:

```
Select 
Non Empty 
    {[Measures].[name of measure]} 
On Columns, 

Non Empty
    {
        (
            [Table 0].[Hierarchy 0].&[Member 0] *
            [Table 1].[Hierarchy 1].Children *
            [Table 2].[Hierarchy 2].Children *
            [Table 2].[Hierarchy 3].Children *
            { [Table 3].[Hierarchy 4].&[Member 1],
              [Table 3].[Hierarchy 4].&[Member 2],
              [Table 3].[Hierarchy 4].&[Member 3],
              [Table 3].[Hierarchy 4].&[Member 4],
              [Table 3].[Hierarchy 4].&[Member 5]
            }
        )
    }
On Rows 
From [DB]
```

Description: On columns, there's a set followed by a big tuple with multiple cross joins. I explicitly select some members in order to filter them.

Code 2:

```
Select 
Non Empty 
    {[Measures].[name of measure]} 
On Columns, 

Non Empty  
    ( 
    {[Table 0].[Hierarchy 0].&[Member 0]} *
        ( { [Table 1].[Hierarchy 1].Children } *
            ( { [Table 2].[Hierarchy 2].Children } *
                ( { [Table 2].[Hierarchy 3].Children } *
                  {[Table 3].[Hierarchy 4].&[Member 1],
                  [Table 3].[Hierarchy 4].&[Member 2],
                  [Table 3].[Hierarchy 4].&[Member 3],
                  [Table 3].[Hierarchy 4].&[Member 4],
                  [Table 3].[Hierarchy 4].&[Member 5]} 
                )  
            )  
        )  
    )  
On Rows 
From [DB]
```

Description: Nested tuples and sets.

I've got the first code from my mind and the 2nd one from a query generator. They both give me the same output, but I can't get my head wrapped around the concept on the 2nd one. Why are there so many tuples and sets?

Which would be the optimal version?

Comment: I think both should be fine and perform about the same. Go with the one that’s easier to read in your mind.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know what’s the reason for using nested sets/ tuples?

Comment: just optional {} and () that aren’t required. I find the first more readable